# Power series expansion for inverse square root

Tags: binomial-theorem

I'm looking at a question where I have to prove that:

$$(1-z)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}k\frac{z^k}{2^{2k}}$$

The hint is to use the generalised Binomial Theorem. I'm having trouble getting the expected answer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem has: $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^s}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{s+k-1}{k}z^k$$

So as I see it, the series should be:

$$(1-z)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k-1/2}kz^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1/2(1/2-1)(1/2-2)...(1/2-k+1)}{k!}z^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1-2)(1-4)...(1-2k+2)}{k!}\frac{z^k}{2^k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(3)(5)(7)...(2k-3)}{k!}\frac{-(-z)^k}{2^k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-3)!}{k!(2)(4)...(2k-4)}\frac{-(-z)^k}{2^k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-3)!}{k!(k-2)!}\frac{-(-z)^k}{2^k2^{k-2}}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k!}{k!(k-2)!}\frac{-(-z)^k}{2^k2^{k-2}(2k-2)(2k-1)2k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}k\frac{-(-z)^kk(k-1)}{2^k2^{k-2}(2k-2)(2k-1)2k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}k\frac{-(-z)^k}{2^{2k}(2k-1)}$$

So I've ended up with something close, but have an extra factor and some sign issues. Any clues as to where I've gone wrong?

Comment: One error is at the beginning.  You failed to notice that it was $(1-z)^{-1/2}$, instead of $(1+z)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Why do you have $k-(1/2)\choose k$, and not $-1/2\choose k$?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've edited the question to show the formula that I started from, but I think I've used it correctly.

Comment: Ah, I see an issue. When I expand the binomial at the beginning, I dropped the k part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the generalized binomial theorem,
$$
(1-z)^{-1/2}=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}{k}(-z)^k
$$
so your task is to prove that
$$
(-1)^k\binom{-1/2}{k}=\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}
$$
This is surely true for $k=0$. Next, by induction,
$$
(-1)^{k+1}\binom{-1/2}{k+1}=
-(-1)^k\binom{-1/2}{k}\frac{-1/2-k}{k+1}=
\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2k+1}{k+1}
$$

Comment: Thanks. The factor in the solution is $\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$, but that works out because you need an extra $k+1$ in the denominator and a $2k+2$ in the numerator to take the binomial term to the $k+1$ version, so they almost cancel, but give an additional 2 in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've got there:

$$(1-z)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k-1/2}kz^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(k-1/2)(k-1/2-1)(k-1/2-2)...(k-1/2-k+1)}{k!}z^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)(2k-3)(2k-5)...(1)}{k!}\frac{z^k}{2^k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!}{k!(k-1)!}\frac{z^k}{2^k2^{k-1}}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}\frac{z^k}{2^k2^k}$$